# We have 3 times 'A', 4 times 'Y' and 5 times 'Z'. Count the number of strings that there are no consecutive same characters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

So I need to find the number of  strings with  **3 times 'A', 4 times 'Y' and 5 times 'Z'** such that there are **no consecutive same characters**.

I was thinking from all strings to substract those with "AA", "BB" or "CC" as substring. But I can't find those. And to substract them maybe I need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I am not sure.

Any tips?